# how to select the earliest time from a datetime database field?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, ms-access-2007

My database has a table with an `userId`, an `userName`, a number field that saves an ID for each datetime and a datetime field that records every time the user logs-in and logs-out.

The thing is that logs comes from a fingerprint catcher, and the software that controls the logs is not programmed for avoiding  duplicate logs. So, an user can put his finger and save a log-in/log-out hour each time.

My mission is to create a program that would split the datetime field's data in two new datetime fields in another database, one for the log-in hours and another for the log-outs. To achieve that I have to use the ID field that stores a 0 value for the log-ins and 1 to 5 for the log-outs, but I'm out of ideas on how to avoid the duplicates. And if you can give me a good hint on how to achieve the split in a smooth way, it would be lovely.

I have to use ms acces 2007, visual studio 2012 and c# language. Thanks in advance for your attention.

PD: I'm from colombia, thats why my english is a little messy and old.

EDIT: here is an example of my table.

|IdUser||||||||RecordTime||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| RecordType |

|399---||||||||28/04/2016 06:55:36 a.m.|||||----- 0----------|

|399---||||||||28/04/2016 06:57:32 a.m.|||||------0----------|

|399---||||||||28/04/2016 05:07:15 p.m.|||||------1----------|

|399---||||||||28/04/2016 05:16:33 p.m.|||||------1----------|

|399---||||||||02/05/2016 07:04:02 a.m.|||||------0----------|

|399---||||||||02/05/2016 05:15:53 p.m.|||||------1----------|

Comment: Is it possible to add some data from your database to make it clearer. Because i don't get the question.

Comment: it was a real pain to create that "table".

Comment: as you can see, this user log-in hour is in the morning, and his log-out hour is in the afternoon. the log hours are in the RecordTime field, the log-in hours have a RecordType value of 0, the log-out hours have a value of 1 to 5 (i didn't design this database, it is created by the fingerprint catcher program). the problem is in the duplicate values, if they were not there, i could take the log-in hours and the log-out hours and split them in two fields or tables, selecting them by their RecordType

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how big this database of yours is and wether it would be possible to do a cron job every week/day to port the data into the new Database, but i'm going to try explain the concept of my solutions. It's up to you to implement it.

I would use the following method:

- Read all the logs of one User into an array with the following fields (*If there is too much data, select ranges of datetime with every pass*)
- Sort that array 
       -> This should give you changing rows in the RecordType (*eg. 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5..*)
- Then write that array (*Chronologicaly!*) into the new database which has a Unique ID key.
- Then you remove this data from the old database in order to not port the same data twice.
- Run this every day/week with a cronjob.

It's up to you to implement it. But that is the strategy i would use.

Then you should end up with the following database:

ID|||||IdUser||||||||RecordTime||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| RecordType |

```
1|||||399---||||||||28/04/2016 06:55:36 a.m.|||||----- 0----------|

2|||||399---||||||||28/04/2016 06:57:32 a.m.|||||------0----------|

3|||||399---||||||||28/04/2016 05:07:15 p.m.|||||------1----------|

4|||||399---||||||||28/04/2016 05:16:33 p.m.|||||------1----------|

5|||||399---||||||||02/05/2016 07:04:02 a.m.|||||------0----------|

6|||||399---||||||||02/05/2016 05:15:53 p.m.|||||------1----------|
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, the idea of taking two different types of data from a table, without the proper identification, is wrong. Different types of data should always be in different tables. 
My boss (i do not know how), resulted to be very illustrated in the ways of programing, and he, after clarifying his needs, gave me a way to make this solution to work:

First, you take the table, and use it to fill an array of any kind, in my case, a DataGridView:

```
try
        {
            huella.Open();
            OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand();
            comando.Connection = huella;
            string consulta = "select [User].IdUser,[User].IdentificationNumber,[User].name,[Record].RecordTime," +
                "[Record].RecordType from [User] inner join [Record] on [User].IdUser = [Record].IdUser " +

            "where " + "[Record].IdUser=@01 and [Record].RecordTime between @time1 and @time2 order by [User].IdUser asc,[Record].RecordTime asc";
            comando.CommandText = consulta;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@01", IDcm.Text.ToString());
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time1", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time2", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
            OleDbDataAdapter datos = new OleDbDataAdapter(comando);
            // using( OleDbDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader())
            tabla = new DataTable();
            datos.Fill(tabla);
            //MessageBox.Show(""+tabla);
            clu.DataSource = tabla;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            huella.Close();
        }
```

Then, you loop throughout the array's data, assigning the first value of the array to a variable. Inside this loop, you start another loop, to assign the second value of the array  to another variable, and finally, you compare this two variables, to assign them to their respective places (following your own criteria):

```
StreamWriter archivo = new StreamWriter("D:\\MAXIMUM PC.csv", true);
        {
            archivo.WriteLine('"' + "usuario" + '"' + ";" + '"' + "Hora de entrada" + '"' + ";" + '"' + "Hora de salida" + '"' + ";" + '"' + "Tiempo" + '"' + ";" + '"' + "Pago" + '"');
            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                //assign the first variable, in my case, DateTime data types
                fechaHora = Convert.ToDateTime(clu.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                for (j = i + 1; j < rows; j++)
                {
                    //assign the second variable
                    fechaActual = Convert.ToDateTime(clu.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    if (fechaHora.Date == fechaActual.Date)
                    {

                        //here i start the compare process
                        if (fechaHora.TimeOfDay != fechaActual.TimeOfDay)
                        {
                            tiempo = fechaActual.Subtract(fechaHora);
                            // if the dates are the same, but their time is different..
                            if (tiempo.TotalHours > 7 && fechaHora.TimeOfDay > fechaActual.TimeOfDay)
                            {
                                //if the timespan between the times is over 7 hours and the first date is over the second....
                                entrada = fechaHora;
                                salida = fechaActual;
                                pay = Convert.ToDouble(tiempo.TotalHours * hourPay);
                                archivo.WriteLine(usuario + ";" + entrada + ";" + salida + ";" + tiempo.TotalHours + ";" + pay);

                            }
                            //if the timespan between the times is over 7 hours and the second date is over the fist....
                            else if (tiempo.TotalHours > 7 && fechaHora.TimeOfDay < fechaActual.TimeOfDay)
                            {
                                entrada = fechaHora;
                                salida = fechaActual;
                                pay = Convert.ToDouble(tiempo.TotalHours * hourPay);
                                archivo.WriteLine(usuario + ";" + entrada + ";" + salida + ";" + tiempo.TotalHours + ";" + pay);
                            }
                            //if the timespan between the times is under 2 hours and the first date is under or equal the second....
                            else if (tiempo.TotalHours < 2 && fechaHora.TimeOfDay <= fechaActual.TimeOfDay)
                            {
                                error = fechaActual;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for all your help, i hope this will be useful.